# Combined UUID Index + AI PK Insert Performance

Tags: mysql, insert

I posted this in stackoverflow but realised it probably belongs here instead.

Imagine the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
     `ORDERID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `DATE` date NOT NULL,
     `UUID` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ORDERID`),
     UNIQUE KEY `UUID` (`UUID`),
    );
```

The UUID and DATE is generated client side. If I insert 100 million rows into this table, the insert time will increase quite a lot because of the UUID unique constraint, as mysql must be sure that the UUID doesn't already exist. And I use the term "quite a lot" in comparison with only using AI PK.

But, if I do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
     `ORDERID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `DATE` date NOT NULL,
     `UUID` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ORDERID`),
     UNIQUE KEY `UUID` (`DATE`,`UUID`),
    );
```

And add the combination of date and UUID as a unique constraint, instead of only the UUID, and increment the date by one day every 10.000 rows or so - will the performance be better because the server only has to check an index of a maximum of 10.000 rows, since it already has an ordered list of dates?

I can only find documentation about the performance of indexes for SELECT - not for INSERT. Can anyone explain to me if the logic in the above question is completely flawed?

Comment: With only 10K rows inserted per day (that is about 7 rows per minute), I would not worry about insert performance. Choose the indexes according to what queries you plan to run.

Comment: If I did not understand correct, and you plan to insert the 100M rows in one go, it's a different issue. You still need to index according to your queries but it could be faster to insert first and then add the indexes.

Comment: No, the 100 million would be for stress test comparison. These rows would typically come in 10.000 rows a day for - let's say 10 years.

The question is rather simple, actually. I might have made it more complex than necessary: If I insert into this table, and 100.000 rows exist for one date, but 1 billion exist in total. Would it be faster if it could use the combined date-uuid index, and not uuid alone, to limit the unique constraint to only 100.000 rows?

Comment: And the select queries would never touch the UUID. They would use the primary key only - and date and other stuff. But they would not care about the unique index really.

Comment: Anyone? I'm still at a loss. Does the INSERT statement automatically perform a SELECT statement if a column is unique? If so then that would answer my question, but I can't find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: If the UUID is never touched, then it is a red herring.  A _big_ _fat_ red herring.  This is because UUIDs are so random that they mess up any caching scheme, both on INSERTs and SELECTs.  Is it 36.5M rows, or a billion rows?  That also _may_ make a big difference.  And how many other fields will the real table have?  And what do the SELECTs look like?  Seriously, your stripped down benchmark is only causing you to ask the wrong questions.  And we haven't gotten into PARTITION options yet.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid and other of my blogs.

Comment: @RickJames See the question I posted in StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084901/how-does-mysql-determine-if-an-insert-is-unique
I don't see any other way I can make sure an order is unique when they are generated client side.

Comment: I added a thorough analysis of things to the stackoverflow thread.